# SQL with aggregate function with two rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

I have the following tables:

[image: Table definitions]

and I'm working on a query that returns the number of voters (the `idcard` number), who have voted in the municipality m1. As can be seen, the municipality n1 has two districts: 1 and 2, which have different voters. This is my code:

```
SELECT COUNT(idcard) FROM Census
WHERE ndistrict = (SELECT ndistrict FROM Polling WHERE name='m1')
```

But I have the problem that the subquery returns two rows, so the count cannot be done. Could someone enlighten me?

Comment: Please remember to provide data as *text*, not as image. And always disclose your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT count(*) AS votes
FROM  (SELECT ndistrict FROM polling WHERE name = 'm1') p
JOIN   census USING (ndistrict);
```

Works for any number of rows returned from subquery `p`.
It assumes no duplicates from that subquery (given since `ndistrict` is the PK of `polling` according to your table definition), and `idcard` to be defined `NOT NULL` (so that the faster `count(*)` is equivalent to `count(idcard)`.

It returns the **number of votes**, which is not necessarily the same as:

> the number of voters (the idcard number), who have voted in the municipality 'm1'

If the same voter can have cast multiple votes, to count **distinct voters**:

```sql
SELECT count(DISTINCT idcard) AS voters
FROM  (SELECT ndistrict FROM polling WHERE name = 'm1') p
JOIN   census USING (ndistrict);
```

Comment: Brilliant solution for one municipality.

Answer (score 0):

that depends if ndistrict  are identical or different

identical

```
SELECT COUNT(idcard) FROM Census
WHERE ndistrict = (SELECT DISTINCT ndistrict FROM Polling WHERE name='m1')
```

If there are multiple ndistrict  use

```
SELECT COUNT(idcard) FROM Census
WHERE ndistrict IN (SELECT DISTINCT ndistrict FROM Polling WHERE name='m1')
```